# How can we run a script through Abaqus using OS Command in ISight?

Tags: optimization, command, abaqus, isight

I am trying to perform an optimzation task using ISight. I need to run a Python script through Abaqus for the latter. However, when using the Abaqus Application component, some parameters cannot be selected. I am therefore using the Data Exchanger with an OS Command but what is the command to launch a script through Abaqus using the OS Command Component?

In the Windows Command line, I would normally type:
abaqus cae script=scriptname.py

However with this line, the ISight log outputs that the "system cannot find the log specified".
In addition, in the OS Command window, under "find a program",when I search in the SIMULIA folder, only ISight is present and not CAE. I am using the same ISight and Abaqus version.

Does anyone have an advice regarding this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the 'OS Command' component and changing Type to 'Windows Batch'